# Check if parameter is set before checking post value in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

I'm making some sort of blog in CodeIgniter.
A key aspect of a blog is the creation and updating of posts.

I'd like to reuse the view I'm using for creating a post, to update it.
For this, I'd like to pass the post data to the form.

When a validation error occurs, the form should display the data passed to it, instead of the parameter data.

So I want to pass data to the form, but after posting, the `set_value` method must override the parameter.

So far, I have this form to create a post.
As said before, I'd like to adapt this form so I can reuse it for updating a post.

```
<h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>

<?php
    echo form_open('posts/' . $function);
    echo form_fieldset();
    echo '<legend>' . $title . '</legend>';

    echo form_hidden('id', (isset($id) ? $id : '0'));
    echo form_input('title', set_value('title', 'Title'), 'size="50"');
    echo '<input type="date" name="date" id="date" value="' . 
            form_prep(set_value('date', date('Y-m-d'))) . 
            '" />';
    echo form_textarea('content', set_value('content', ''));
    echo form_input('category', set_value('category', 'Category'), 'size="50"');
    echo form_input('keywords', set_value('keywords', 'Keywords'), 'size="50"');

    echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit');
    echo '<input type="reset" name="clear" value="Clear" />';

    echo form_fieldset_close();
    echo form_close();
?>
```

`$function` is supposed to hold *create* or *update*.
`$title` is *Create post* or *Update post* and does not affect the forms function.
I already added a hidden field for the posts id, used when updating a post.

I thought of using parameters sent to the view and using `isset` to check for their existance, thus making the difference between creating or updating a post. But this would conflict with the `set_value`.
I'm not quite sure if it would be possible to post data to the form and what the consequences would be.

Comment: could you please explain a bit , what do you mean by `parameter data`. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is to fill the `$_POST` array with values before loading the view.

```
$_POST['title'] = $old_retrieved_title;
$_POST['content'] = $old_retrieved_content;
$_POST['category'] = $old_retrieved_category;
$_POST['keywords'] = $old_retrieved_keywords;
$this->load->view(...);
```

This will allow `set_value()` to see the values previously entered and retrieved from your database (or whatever). The CodeIgniter function `set_value()` is designed to "rebuild" a form after a POST operation in which the submission did not meet some requirement (usually empty/wrong fields). In this case, to be nice to the user, the desire is to set the field vlaues to the "old" field values just submitted. In order to do this, the function looks in `$_POST` to retrieve those values for the fields (assuming you use it in the usual way that you clearly are).

(With regard to performance: any overhead imposed by what I am suggesting is extremely trivial and as the operation is clear part of a network transaction, any impact is extremely unlikely to be measurable in practice.)

Comment: As you were the first to answer, you might help me with the question I left behind at the other answer

Comment: I expanded my answer.

Answer (score 1):

While you could set each value of $_POST to its proper value, you may be incurring overhead if you're not using some of those variavles.  A more effecient way would be:

```
$_POST['category'] = (isset($_POST['category'])?"my_catehory":"default_category");
```

Now keep in mind that if you're accessing twenty, thirty, etc. of sixty total variables, it'd be more efficient to populate the entire `$_POST` variable.

Is storing the variables in a session a reasonable solution?  It would eliminate the work of having to wonder if `$_POST` is populated every time.

Finally, if you must populate:

```
function populate_post_vars() {
  $_POST['one'] = $old_retrieved_one;
  $_POST['two'] = $old_retrieved_two;
  if (!isset($POST['three']) $POST['three'] = '3';
  // I think you get the idea.
}

populate_post_vars();
$this->load->view(...);  /*Credit to @Dwayne Towell for some minor code hints*/
```

Comment: I'm currently unable to test, so I'll just ask you. If I understand correctly, on updating a post I get all details and put them in $_POST. Loading the view will automaticly load the $_POST and will enter the values in the correct fields by using the set_value that is currently being used?

Comment: Using set_value() should result in what you are looking for.  However, keep in mind that Frameworks have overhead and the fewer calls, the better (a fact I think is often overlooked).  If you can come up with any clever ways to populate $_POST without risk, I'd go for it.  If you still run into problems I will install Codeigniter and write up some working code for you.

Comment: @JakeGould -- Thanks for the edits; I'm still fairly new to Stack Overflow and doing the best I can.  THanks.  -- Trick

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am using for keeping when a validation error occurs, the form display the data passed to it, instead of the parameter data. Setting the posted value in the set_value() method.

```
echo form_input('title', set_value('title', this->input->post('title') );
```

Comment: Could you write a short explanation why this solves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same thing as you and used a submission and editing view for the same thing, this is how I solved it.

```
function get_value($backup, $post_name) {
    $CI = &get_instance();
    if ($CI->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST') {
        return $CI->input->post($post_name);
    }

    if ($backup === null) {
        return "";
    }

    return $backup;
}
```

And

```
function get_value_from_object($object, $field, $post_name) {
    $CI = &get_instance();

    if ($CI->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST') {
        return set_value($post_name);
    }

    if ($object === null) {
        return "";
    }

    return $object->$field; 
}
```

Depending on the kind of value/forum I'm using, usually going with the latter if my form represents and object.

Demonstrated like so:-

```
<input type="text name="persons_name" value="<?php echo get_value_from_object($person, 'name', 'person_name'); ?>">
```

On the creation page $person will be null so it will first try take it from POST, if it wasn't a post request (I.E the form submission hasn't failed); then it will give back an empty string.

Otherwise it will try and take the property 'name' from $person, so $person->name

**EDIT**: All of these functions are in a helper I created for form actions

Answer (score 0):

you can only use this:

```
if($this->input->post('post_value_name')){
     // code here. ...
}
```

that's it.